# Smooth transition div height for responsive websites with mootools

Tags: mootools, responsive-design

Currently working on responsive webdesign and the markup is completely finished and works fine in all browser widths . But I cant leave it alone . Trying to size the height of news holding div with some smooth transition instead of the jerk drop.

I setup a jsfiddle for anyone that would like to help with this and I am sure it will come handy to anyone working with responsive web designs.
http://jsfiddle.net/rYQtb/10/

many thnx!

Comment: Do you want a smooth javascript method to " with some smooth transition instead of the jerk drop.", or do you want a css transition? I am sorry if I not quite able to understand your question

Comment: @AZInventor either one that actually works nice, I would prefer a mootools technique if you know any but css3 transition could also help.

Comment: doesn't this defeat the purpose? see http://bricss.net/post/22198838298/easily-checking-in-javascript-if-a-css-media-query-has?04001770 - you should use js to check what media queries have run and tie the two together, not have new size logic running independently.

Answer (score 0):

I think for what you want to do you need a listener on the resize event so i've added one.

I tried something here started with your fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/rYQtb/15/
I've updated the JavaScript and the CSS (added an overflow value).
But did you want the height fixed on the global div (like the fiddle) or on each 'news' div ?

Hope it will be helpful !

Comment: very nice start , the issue is that we cant have the overflow auto or the scroll visible. I think if each new div gets the height fixed plus the holder we can have a nice animation

Comment: I think you should choose between fixing height on each 'news' div or on the main div. Both will be weird. I'll test since i get few times. For the overflow don't forget that if you put an overflow:hidden; in some cases the content may be inaccessible..

Comment: I've tested both fix height on the main container and on the divs and it's weird and buddy. I've also tested to put the fix heights on each 'news' div and the result is the same (look logic), for changing overflow you just have to change the property in hidden :)